# Android ListView doesn't show content when fragment is initiated for the first time

Tags: android, listview, sharedpreferences, json

I have a listview in a fragment with a customadapter loading a list of products from my mysql database. When I navigate to the fragment from my navigation drawer activity for the 1st time, it doesn't show any items but the same get printed in the log. But when the same fragment is initiated 2nd time, all items are visible.
Here is my code from the onCreateView() of fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_complain, container, false);
    sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    new BackgroundViewComplainTask().execute();
    jsonString = sharedPreferences.getString("complain", "");
    complainList = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list);
    addComplain = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.addComplain);
    String productName, serial, complainType, complainMessage, added_on;
    viewComplainAdapter = new ViewComplainAdapter(this.getActivity(), R.layout.complain_layout);
    try {
        Log.d("json",jsonString);
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");
        int count = 0;
        ViewComplainsList viewComplainsList;

        while (count<jsonArray.length()){
            JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
            productName = JO.getString("productName");
            serial = JO.getString("serial");
            complainType = JO.getString("complainType");
            complainMessage = JO.getString("complainMessage");
            added_on = JO.getString("added_on");
            viewComplainsList = new ViewComplainsList(complainMessage, complainType, productName, serial, added_on);
            viewComplainAdapter.add(viewComplainsList);
            count++;
        }
        complainList.setAdapter(viewComplainAdapter);
        viewComplainAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(jsonString.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"No Complains found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        this.startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class));
    }
    addComplain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_activity_frame, new AddComplainFragment()).addToBackStack("complainFragment").commit();
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

**jsonString** does get printed in the log.

Here is my activity log:

> 06-08 15:08:27.450 10110-10110/com.example.thadaninilesh.productapp W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
>   06-08 15:08:27.450 10110-10110/com.example.thadaninilesh.productapp W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
>   06-08 15:08:27.450 10110-10110/com.example.thadaninilesh.productapp W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
>   06-08 15:08:27.450 10110-10110/com.example.thadaninilesh.productapp W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:156)
>   06-08 15:08:27.450 10110-10110/com.example.thadaninilesh.productapp W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:173)
>   06-08 15:08:27.450 10110-10110/com.example.thadaninilesh.productapp W/System.err:     at com.example.thadaninilesh.productapp.ViewComplainFragment.onCreateView(ViewComplainFragment.java:72)
>   06-08 15:08:27.450 10110-10110/com.example.thadaninilesh.productapp W/System.err:     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2053)
>   06-08 15:08:27.450 10110-10110/com.example.thadaninilesh.productapp W/System.err:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:894)
>   06-08 15:08:27.450 10110-10110/com.example.thadaninilesh.productapp W/System.err:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
>   06-08 15:08:27.450 10110-10110/com.example.thadaninilesh.productapp W/System.err:     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:834)
>   06-08 15:08:27.450 10110-10110/com.example.thadaninilesh.productapp W/System.err:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1452)
>   06-08 15:08:27.450 10110-10110/com.example.thadaninilesh.productapp W/System.err:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:447)
>   06-08 15:08:27.450 10110-10110/com.example.thadaninilesh.productapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>   06-08 15:08:27.450 10110-10110/com.example.thadaninilesh.productapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>   06-08 15:08:27.450 10110-10110/com.example.thadaninilesh.productapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>   06-08 15:08:27.450 10110-10110/com.example.thadaninilesh.productapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>   06-08 15:08:27.450 10110-10110/com.example.thadaninilesh.productapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   06-08 15:08:27.450 10110-10110/com.example.thadaninilesh.productapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>   06-08 15:08:27.450 10110-10110/com.example.thadaninilesh.productapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>   06-08 15:08:27.450 10110-10110/com.example.thadaninilesh.productapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>   06-08 15:08:27.480 10110-10394/com.example.thadaninilesh.productapp D/response: {"server_response":[{"serial":"123456789QWERT","complainType":"qwerty","complainMessage":"The body is completely damaged","added_on":"08-06-2016","productName":"Acer Travelmate"},{"serial":"123456789QWERT","complainType":"qwerty","complainMessage":"The body is completely damaged","added_on":"08-06-2016","productName":"Acer Travelmate"},{"serial":"123456789QWERT","complainType":"qwerty","complainMessage":"The body is completely damaged","added_on":"08-06-2016","productName":"Acer Travelmate"},{"serial":"123456789QWERT","complainType":"qwertyu","complainMessage":"The body is completely damaged","added_on":"08-06-2016","productName":"Acer Travelmate"},{"serial":"123456789QWERT","complainType":"Physical Condition","complainMessage":"--","added_on":"08-06-2016","productName":"Acer Travelmate"},{"serial":"12345678DFGBH","complainType":"sdcwsdw","complainMessage":"wdwdf","added_on":"08-06-2016","productName":"Galaxy J7"},{"serial":"12345678DFGBH","complainType":"asd","complainMessage":"--","added_on":"08-06-2016 08:06","productName":"Galaxy J7"}]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it...
The problem was the sequence of execution. After calling the Asynctask I was not waiting for it to complete rather was populating the listview before getting the json string from server.
Solved it by populating the listview in the onPostExecute method of Asynctask.
Thanks for those who tried helping me.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `viewComplainAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` before fetching your data.

You should call it after creating your `Fragment`, or at least after fetching your data:

```
while (count<jsonArray.length()){
    JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
    if(JO.getString("productName").isEmpty()){
        startActivity(new Intent(this.getActivity(), LoginActivity.class));
    }
    productName = JO.getString("productName");
    serial = JO.getString("serial");
    complainType = JO.getString("complainType");
    complainMessage = JO.getString("complainMessage");
    added_on = JO.getString("added_on");
    Log.d("productName",productName);
    ViewComplainsList viewComplainsList = new ViewComplainsList(complainMessage, complainType, productName, serial, added_on);
    viewComplainAdapter.add(viewComplainsList);
    count++;
}

viewComplainAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // here
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below code.

viewComplainAdapter = new ViewComplainAdapter(this.getActivity(), R.layout.complain_layout);
    complainList.setAdapter(viewComplainAdapter);
Here You are creating object of ViewComplainAdapter class with Activity context and the layout resource, as such there is no data you are passing to show. So First time of fragment instantiation, listview is not able to show any data.

After that you are sending request to your server.Check the below line.

new BackgroundViewComplainTask().execute();

After getting response from server,your are adding the value to ViewComplainAdapter .

```
    while (count<jsonArray.length()){
        JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);

        productName = JO.getString("productName");
        serial = JO.getString("serial");
        complainType = JO.getString("complainType");
        complainMessage = JO.getString("complainMessage");
        added_on = JO.getString("added_on");
        Log.d("productName",productName);
        ViewComplainsList viewComplainsList = new ViewComplainsList(complainMessage, complainType, productName, serial, added_on);
        viewComplainAdapter.add(viewComplainsList);
        count++;
    }
```

So when you are calling Fragment for second time, ViewComplainAdapter is able to show data in the listviw.

To fix this issue, after getting response only, set adapter with listview, so that you can see Fragment with list of data without fail.

Comment: I have updated the code... I'm saving my json data in sharedPreferences and the retrieving them.. But it returns nothing

Comment: Okey, how are you putting json data into sharedpreference. Can you post that code. I think you are not putting data into sharedpreference correctly, so only its returning nothing.

Comment: SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit(); editor.putString("complain", result); editor.commit();